# how to get week day for given date for using Calendar in android studio

Tags: android

Here is my code:

```
// Date birthDay;
            GregorianCalendar birthDay = new GregorianCalendar();

            birthDay.set(year_int,mo,da,0,0,0);
            int weekday = birthDay.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
            String weekDay = String.valueOf(weekday -1);
            weekDay = weekDay.replace("0","Sunday.");
            weekDay = weekDay.replace("1","Monday.");
            weekDay = weekDay.replace("2","Tuesday.");
            weekDay = weekDay.replace("3","Wednesday.");
            weekDay = weekDay.replace("4","Thursday.");
            weekDay = weekDay.replace("5","Friday.");
            weekDay = weekDay.replace("6","Saturday.");
```

What's wrong here? Please help me.

Comment: What is "What's wrong"? Please describe your error. Note that `get(DAY_OF_WEEK)` returns a value between 0 and 6, so your code is wrong there. Furthermore, look up `Calendar.getDisplayName`.

Answer (score 0):

Use joda-time instead.

```
DateTime birthDay = new DateTime(year, mo,day, 0, 0, 0);
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEEE");
String weekDay = birthday.toString(format);
```

Will return day of week.

If you want to use Calendar:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");    
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, mo,day, 0, 0, 0);   
String weekDay =  sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
```